# Cannot open url with inAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova

I have been hacking away at this app for awhile now in xcode.  I have built several html pages and integrated the inAppBrowser so url's open in the devices default browser.  This works perfect on all my other pages but when I try to do the same thing with this particular page, the url never opens?  I feel like this is a javascript error but my JS knowledge is very minimum at best.

How can I get the url to open on this particular page with inAppBrowser like it does on the other ones?  Nothing is different except this page has its own JS for playing media.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thx

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />



        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"> -->

        <title>My App</title>


        <style>
            * {
                -webkit-touch-callout: none;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
            }
            </style>



    </head>
    <body>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.ios.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="video.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function playbeachcam(){
                document.getElementById('bankschanneldiv').style.display= "none";
                document.getElementById('beachcamdiv').style.display= "block";
                document.getElementById('looperscamdiv').style.display= "none";


               // window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("http://.../playlist.m3u8");
            }

            function playloopercam(){
                document.getElementById('bankschanneldiv').style.display= "none";
                document.getElementById('beachcamdiv').style.display= "none";
                document.getElementById('looperscamdiv').style.display= "block";


               // window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("http://.../playlist.m3u8");
            }

            function playbankcam(){
                document.getElementById('bankschanneldiv').style.display= "block";
                document.getElementById('beachcamdiv').style.display= "none";
                document.getElementById('looperscamdiv').style.display= "none";

                //window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("http://.../playlist.m3u8");
            }

            function openHome() {
                var ref = window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes');
                ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
                ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
                ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
            }

            </script>



        <div class="header-container" data-role="header">


            <div style=" text-align:left;margin-left:15px;">
                <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><img style="width: 59px; height: 50px" src="img/wbl-logo.png" />
                    <span style="width:auto;position:absolute;bottom:25%;margin-left:10px;font-size:22px;color:#07a54a;">My App</span></a>
            </div> <!-- end logo -->
            <div style="text-align:right;width:auto;position:absolute;right:5%;top:30%;">
                <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-c" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide" data-role="button" href="#menu" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text" style="color:#0267a6;">MENU</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div><!-- end menu -->

        </div><!-- end header -->

        <div class="content-container" data-role="content">

            <div id="wrapper" style="bottom:5px;">
                <div id="main-content">


                    <button id="BeachCam" onClick="playbeachcam();" >
                        Play Beach Cam
                    </button>
                    <br/>
                    <button id="LooperStar" onClick="playloopercam();">
                        Play Looper Cam
                    </button>
                    <br/>
                    <button id="BanksChannel" onClick="playbankcam();">
                        Play Banks Cam
                    </button>


                    <div id = "bankschanneldiv" style="display:none;">

                        <video
                            id="mediaplayer1"
                            controls="1"
                            autoplay="1"
                            height="218"
                            preload="none"
                            src="http://.../playlist.m3u8"
                            width="100%">
                        </video>

                    </div>
                    <div id = "beachcamdiv" style="display:none;">

                        <video
                            id="mediaplayer2"
                            controls="1"
                            autoplay="1"
                            height="218"
                            preload="none"
                            src="http://.../playlist.m3u8"
                            width="100%">
                        </video>

                    </div>
                    <div id = "looperscamdiv" style="display:none;">

                        <video
                            id="mediaplayer3"
                            controls="1"
                            autoplay="1"
                            height="218"
                            preload="none"
                            src="http://.../playlist.m3u8"
                            width="100%">
                        </video>

                    </div>





                    <p style="color:#f4f4f4;">Having Trouble?</p>
                    <p><a style="color:#07a54a;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333;" href="#" onclick='openHome()' target="_blank" >View the cams on our website</a></p>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer ui-bar-a" data-role="footer" role="contentinfo">
            <div style="text-align:center;width:auto;margin:10px 0;">
                <a href="#" onclick='openHome()' target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#291e0f;">My Footer </a>
            </div> <!-- end footer content -->


        </div><!-- end footer -->


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The URL of your sources in the <video> tags don't seem to be valid:
http://.../playlist.m3u8 doesn't go any where.
You probably mean "../playlist.m3u8" without the http://

Comment: Sorry, I just omitted those for privacy.  They actually point to a live url in my source but for safety reasons I omitted for this post.  That unfortunately is not the cause of the inAppBrowser not working in this particular page.

Comment: What URL do you want to open in the InAppBrowser? Also, the logo one is missing a `target="_blank"`. Does it work like you expect if you remove the video JavaScript from the page?

Comment: For example purposes I would just like to pull up Google.  The inAppBrowser works perfectly on every other page.  So I tried creating a new page and link to it from the page pasted above and it doesnt work, however if I link to the new page from the apps index page (not page pasted above) then it works.  So I feel like the problem is in the video javascript, which works fine with for the videos but must be killing any other link I put on the page whether it is a local in app link or link with inAppBrowser.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just tried commenting things out to see what specifically was the cause and this is the problem: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.ios.js"></script>

Now I'm stuck on a work around and how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

After further troubleshooting I found out that this is the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.ios.js"></script>
```

So now I have found a work around and all is resolved.